# extract floating number from list in python

Tags: python, extract

I want to get all the floating numbers from my list a=[ ] and add it into a new list named as the number=[ ]. Can someone help me with this code? Right now it is giving me a blank output.

```
a = ['1.2.1','2.1.2', '4', 'invalid']
numbers = []
for item in a:
    if item == float:
        numbers.append(item)
print(numbers)
```

Desired output:

```
numbers = ['1.2.1','2.1.2']
```

Comment: `1.2.1` and `2.1.2` are not floating numbers.

Comment: How can we get them?

Comment: Do you mean to get strings with numbers separated by dots?

Comment: Yes these 1.2.1, 2.1.2. How can we add them in a new list?

Comment: Can you describe your numbers better, will they always have 2 dots, or can there be both 1.2 and 1.2.3 kinds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.match` with the following regex pattern:

```
import re
a = ['1.2.1', '2.1.2', '4', 'invalid']
print([s for s in a if re.match(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)+$', s)])
```

This outputs:

```
['1.2.1', '2.1.2']
```

Comment: How can I make a new list from output?   newlist=['1.2.1', '2.1.2']

Comment: `newlist = [s for s in a if re.match(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)+$', s)]`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It working perfectly. Can you help me to understand what exactly happens in the code?